# Is it possible to use pairing functions to express if all the values in one array are less than the corresponding value in another?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, matrix, set

Say I have two sets : `A [1,4,0,3,0,3,1]` and `B [6,6,6,6,6,6,6]`.

Is it possible to create a function `f(X`) that expresses A and B as integers such that the following are true.

1. If all values of B are greater than the corresponding value in A then `f(a) <= f(b)`.
2. If all values of B are less than the corresponding value in A then `f(a) > f(b)`.

**Solution so far :**

I can create a function `f(A)` that returns a large prime number made up of the product of the bijection of each member of A with its resulting prime number. e.g

`A[0] = 3`  
 `A[1] = 11` 
 `A[2] = 2` 
 `A[3] = 7` 
 `A[4] = 2` 
 `A[5] = 7` 
 `A[6] = 3`

So `f(A) = 19404` and

`B[0] = 17`  
 `B[1] = 17` 
 `B[2] = 17` 
 `B[3] = 17` 
 `B[4] = 17` 
 `B[5] = 17` 
 `B[6] = 17`

So `f(B) = 24137569`

This method does not hold up and won't work for a lot of values of A e.g
`A [7,1,1,1,1,1,1]` but I don't want to give up on this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Joe

**UPDATE - Question was phrased badly before. Should have read.**

Say I have two sets : `A [1,4,0,3,0,3,1]` and `B [6,6,6,6,6,6,6]`.

Is it possible to create a function `f([X_1,X_2,...,X_n])` that expresses A and B as integers such that the following condition is true.

1. If `∃n(B_n < A_n)` then `f(A) > f(B)`
2. Otherwise `f(A) <= f(B)`.

Comment: Hey, you just completely changed the question! Now `f(X) = sum(X)` is a trivial solution. (Unless `[]` is a valid input to `f`, in which case condition 2 requires `f([]) > f([])` and it's still not possible.)

Comment: @user2357112 sorry for changing the question, please check the clarification update above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sets do not have an order.  You cannot establish a correspondence between their members without a rule to guide that.  It appears that you really want to talk about lists, arrays, vectors, etc. that have some kind of ordering to their elements.

Comment: @RBarryYoung correct. This is an impossible question though even if we switched to arrays or vectors I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let `A = [2, 3]` and `B = [3, 2]`. Since `B_2 < A_2`, we must have `f([2, 3]) > f([3, 2])`.

Switch A and B, so `A = [3, 2]` and `B = [2, 3]`. Since `B_1 < A_1`, we must have `f([3, 2]) > f([2, 3])`.

These conclusions cannot both be true, so there is no valid `f`.

Comment: The example you give would pass my criteria, the logic fails for cases such as `A = [7,1] and B = [5,7]` where `f(A) < f(b)` and this is incorrect

Comment: @JoeAndrews: What do you mean by "pass my criteria"? Are there any possible values of `f([2])` and `f([3])` that pass condition 2?

Comment: Sorry for changing the question, I have made an update above to provide clarity.

Comment: @JoeAndrews: Answer modified.

Comment: @user2357112 - Won't my solution work here? Using only the max of one with min of other?? Please check my answer below. (Using min and max as function somehow).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: You don't seem to define an `f` anywhere, so it doesn't look like you have a solution.

Comment: @user2357112 - Actually, question was significantly modified later on, which made my solution stand incorrect. But, on the other side, I was thinking of a function F(min,max) of both sets which would have been compared to other set's min and max values. That'd give some insight probably. BTW, I ain't sure of a function of such nature(limited knowledge of mathematics/functions).